# Run PowerShell script from url passing parameters

Tags: powershell

Following PsGet example, this is how I run a ps1 from an url:

`(new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString($Url) | iex`

Now, it would be great if I could pass parameters to that script in a one liner like this, but any parameters I pass go to `iex` instead of getting passed to the script.

How can it be done in a one line? Perhaps it can have two chained commands, but three commands is already too much for a one line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create an unnamed scriptblock from the string and then invoke it using the call operator (`&`):

```
& $([scriptblock]::Create((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString($Url))) -param1 argumentvalue
```

Comment: that is cool thanks! btw, wouldn't it work with `iex`, why `&`?